# React Native or Flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter, frameworks

Hi I want to check out a new framework to develop an app. Now I'm wondering about which one to choose, for example React Native or Flutter. Can you give me some suggestions or experiences about what to choose and maybe their advantages or disadvantages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Summary:**

React uses JS, Flutter uses Dart

The learning curve for Flutter is pretty steep since if you don't already know Dart, you're going to have to learn that too as well as a new framework (and reactive programming).

For React Native, it's pretty easy to pick up if you have used React or just JS in general which I'm sure you have.

**Architecture**

Flutter tends to rely on the [BLoC pattern](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern) which is endorsed by Google Developers.

React Native relies on [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) and [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/).

**Ecosystem**

Flutter came out in May 2017 so it has less of an ecosystem than React Native which came out two full years prior.

**Compilation**

Flutter compiles to device-native code which you can change when you create a Flutter project. All of this is done on *one* thread! For intensive works, you might want to use a [Dart Isolate](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a) which spins up a new spot on the memory to do intensive works while Flutter works on the UI and other stuff. Dart is designed for asynchronous workloads. Dart has Streams and Futures (basically Promises in JS). You can use a package that essentially brings in Redux to Dart to allow for Observables (better Promises).

React Native does *not* compile to native-device code and instead compiles to device equivalent. The JS runs on a separate thread and communicates to UI components through bridges. For asynchronous workloads, you can use Promises like in JS.

**Documentation**

As far as documentation goes, React Native wins at being more user-friendly than Flutter. Although, Flutter does have what they call cookbooks with easy to follow along with code samples. Overall, this is up to you.

**Cross Platform**

Flutter allows you to make apps for way more devices than React Native can. React Native is only for Android & iOS (though you can make web apps with [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), thanks @VilleKoo) while Flutter hopes to support desktop, and web apps as well as the aforementioned iOS & Android all from a *single* codebase which is pretty impressive. Keep in mind, web support is in beta and desktop apps are not stable at this moment in time.

**Further reading:**

https://nevercode.io/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-a-developers-perspective/

https://hackr.io/blog/react-native-vs-flutter

https://hackernoon.com/react-native-vs-flutter-which-is-preferred-for-you-bba108f808

Comment: React Native does have support for web with [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

Comment: What `reactive programming` does mean?

Comment: Here's a pretty long article but it's very good https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/ @DevAS

Answer (score -3):

I see that the technical side of the question is covered pretty well by the others, but it's worth having a look at this issue from the standpoint of the technology's popularity, community support, and how it will keep up in the long run. Here is what I've found:

> The category of most loved technologies due to the StackOverflow statistics shows how many specialists began using a particular tool and would like to continue working with it. By this criterion, Flutter’s score is **68.17%**, while React Native has **58.08%** of voices. [Github says](https://octoverse.github.com/) that the number of open source projects is growing day by day. The statistics present the number of contributors to open-source projects. React Native has **9.1k** contributors, while this number for Flutter reaches **13k**. [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=Flutter,React%20Native) is a metric that shows how often a particular query is entered into the search in relation to the overall search volume for a specific period. It means that it estimates a query as a percentage of all search queries in Google. We can see that Flutter’s popularity amounted to nearly twice the React Native. The average number of “Flutter” queries score is **86**, while React Native takes **58**. With Google Trends, we can also analyze how popular other hybrid frameworks are compared to the described two. The statistics have shown us that Flutter is the best hybrid app framework in 2020, and React Native is in second place. Interestingly, if we take the 5 years’ overview instead of 12 months, we can see the whole picture. The trend for Flutter has rapidly grown in the last 3 years’ time. The popularity of React Native and Cordova was stable, and Xamarin’s number of queries is steadily decreasing.

So as you see Flutter gains popularity very quickly, and I am rather surprised how quick it is. It looks like Flutter might be more future-proof because of the wider community, more new modules, and features, which result in better support, more updates, etc.

Here is some additional reading for you on that matter:

[StackOverflow statistics 2021](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted)

[Flutter vs React Native: Which is better?](https://existek.com/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-in-2021/)

[Statistics about other frameworks' popularity](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=Flutter,React%20Native,Native%20Script,Xamarin,Cordova)

Comment: Much of the content of this post is taken directly from the article you referenced but without any clear marker that it's an excerpt. Do you have permission to reproduce this content? At minimum, it should be in a block quote to clearly delineate it.

Comment: A better answer is to draw from your own experience the merits and flaws of each technology' rather than a copy-and-paste content from the article. Personally, I use Flutter because of its speed, hot-reload and pretty UI. :-)